# PHP replace tags with dynamic values including IF condition

Tags: php

Replacing the dynamic values in PHP can be achieved using code like this:

```
$replace = array('{COVER_AMT}','{LIABILITY_AMT}','{TOTAL_AMT}');
$with = array('90', '90', '0');

$myString = 'This is Cover Amt : {COVER_AMT} . This is liablity amount :     {LIABILITY_AMT} . This is total amount : {TOTAL_AMT}';

echo str_replace($replace, $with, $myString);
```

output:

```
This is Cover Amt : 90 . This is liablity amount : 90 . This is total amount : 0
```

This will give the correct output.

But when the value is 0 it should not be displaying the text itself. For this case, This is total Amount should not be displayed at all as it is 0.

Check with a If condition is not a great solution as it will mess up the code if there are lots of ‘0’s .

If there are around 100 array elements, it will be impossible to check for each values. Any solution that can be used for any number of data inputs will be great.

Any one with a great idea to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: is my solution enough for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not trying something like this:

```
<?php
$replace = array('{COVER_AMT}','{LIABILITY_AMT}','{TOTAL_AMT}', 'This is total amount : 0');
$with = array('90', '90', '0','');

$myString = 'This is Cover Amt : {COVER_AMT} . This is liablity amount :     {LIABILITY_AMT} . This is total amount : {TOTAL_AMT}';


echo str_replace($replace, $with, $myString); 
?>
```

It will only delete last part if total amount is 0.

Acording to edited question:

```
<?php

$replace = array('{COVER_AMT}','{LIABILITY_AMT}','{TOTAL_AMT}');
$with = array('0', '90', '0');

$myString = 'This is Cover Amt : {COVER_AMT} . This is liablity amount :     {LIABILITY_AMT} . This is total amount : {TOTAL_AMT}';

$myString = str_replace($replace, $with, $myString);
$myString_array = explode("This is",$myString);
foreach($myString_array as $myString_sliced) { 
$pattern = '/(\.?)(This is )(.*?) 0(\s?)(\.?)/i';
$replacement = '';
if($myString_sliced)
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, "This is ".$myString_sliced);
}
?>
```

Comment: Ya this could be one of the solution but cannot be extended. This right now has only one value that is 0. Lets say if you have an array with 100 items then this will be impossible. Any other solution would be great.

Comment: @user96675 you should give more details in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

first replace all `0` from empty string, try this code

```
<?php 
$replace = array('{COVER_AMT}','{LIABILITY_AMT}','{TOTAL_AMT}');
$with = array('90', '90', '0');
$with = array_map(function($v){return $v <= 0 ? '' : $v;}, $with);

$myString = 'This is Cover Amt : {COVER_AMT} . This is liablity amount :     {LIABILITY_AMT} . This is total amount : {TOTAL_AMT}';

echo str_replace($replace, $with, $myString);
```